# Cache size limit?

Tags: php

I'm trying to help someone with a calendar application that they have and there is a strange problem where the data being pulled into it all disappears. I wrote a limit of 240 entries into the php and the records all showed, but talking to the person there is another calendar that has more than 240 entries and it displays fine. The case I was working with, once there are more than 240 records, the page returns a server error.

Therefore I was thinking this is an issue where we might be hitting some kind of limit. Perhaps the other calendar might have more records but less over all data being sent. Perhaps the version I am working on has bigger records. That is my idea as to why it is not based on a set number of records or any obvious pattern as to why the data disappears.

All the data is being loaded by the PHP from its source, but once it tries to cache it, the page fails.

```
foreach($grab AS $key=>$item) { 

//gather data code goes here...

$items[$item->item_id] = array(
    "title" => $title,
    "address" => $address,
    "events" => $events,
    "description" => $description,
    "status" => $status[0],
    "region" => $region,
    "date_start" => $date_start,
    "date_end" => $date_end,
    "name" => $name,
    "email" => $email,
    "phone_number" => $phone_number,                   
    "account_representative" => $account_representative,
    "account_representative_details" => $account_representative_details,
    "lodging_info" => $lodging_info,
    "parking_available" => $parking_available,
    "additional_information" => $additional_information
    );
}

$this->cache->save($cache_id, $items, 60);
```

I did an output of $items using print_r and got the expected output in static html, but once `$this->cache->save($cache_id, $items, 60);` is reached, the page fails. It is the last part of the php other than the return.

Therefore I am thinking that we are reaching a limit in the cache. Can someone weigh in and tell my if that sounds like the likely cause? I do not know how to check what the cache limit, nor do I know how to increase it.

The site is hosted on the Amazon AWS services. Any help is appreciated.

Running I get apc_cache_info()

```
Array
(
[nslots] => 4099
[ttl] => 0
[nhits] => 23779
[nmisses] => 12700
[ninserts] => 12282
[nentries] => 51
[nexpunges] => 0
[stime] => 1456460996
[mem_size] => 14673424
[file_upload_progress] => 1
[memory_type] => mmap
[cache_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => 36--16684924
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473604572
                [ctime] => 1473604572
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473604572
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 2222768
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14511725_region
                [ttl] => 120
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473342792
                [ctime] => 1473342792
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473342792
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [key] => 44--15835802
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1473551643
                [ctime] => 1473551643
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473551653
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 2686640
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [key] => 39--14638908
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473445289
                [ctime] => 1473445289
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473445289
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 335024
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15835802_region_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 3
                [mtime] => 1473539525
                [ctime] => 1473539525
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473539959
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15872466_region
                [ttl] => 120
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1472560404
                [ctime] => 1472560404
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1472560404
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [key] => 16701314_region_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1473603775
                [ctime] => 1473603775
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473603775
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15786583_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473571641
                [ctime] => 1473571641
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473571641
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15103330_region
                [ttl] => 120
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1456725907
                [ctime] => 1456725907
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1456725907
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15835802_region
                [ttl] => 120
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473539525
                [ctime] => 1473539525
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473539525
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [key] => 45--15872466
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473444187
                [ctime] => 1473444187
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473444187
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 1623216
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14869157_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1470252787
                [ctime] => 1470252787
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1470255080
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15103330_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 4
                [mtime] => 1456725907
                [ctime] => 1456725907
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1456790634
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [key] => 31--14360206
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 9
                [mtime] => 1473555344
                [ctime] => 1473555344
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473555398
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 822448
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14360206_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 4
                [mtime] => 1473438731
                [ctime] => 1473438731
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473456978
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15103653_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1456790201
                [ctime] => 1456790201
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1456790669
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14869156_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1473449679
                [ctime] => 1473449679
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473449727
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [key] => 16701314_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473603775
                [ctime] => 1473603775
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473603775
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [key] => 36--16685020
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473343453
                [ctime] => 1473343453
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473343453
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 1712
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14360206_region_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 9
                [mtime] => 1473438731
                [ctime] => 1473438731
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473456978
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [20] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14511725_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473257630
                [ctime] => 1473257630
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473257630
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15872466_region_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 6
                [mtime] => 1472560404
                [ctime] => 1472560404
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1472575925
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15835858_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1473454881
                [ctime] => 1473454881
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473540355
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [23] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15872508_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473413915
                [ctime] => 1473413915
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473413915
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [24] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15544702_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1472075488
                [ctime] => 1472075488
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1472075488
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [25] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15103330_region_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 9
                [mtime] => 1456725907
                [ctime] => 1456725907
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1456790634
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [26] => Array
            (
                [key] => 43--14869156
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473571645
                [ctime] => 1473571645
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473571645
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 1786032
            )

        [27] => Array
            (
                [key] => 36--14511725
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1473218252
                [ctime] => 1473218252
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473218262
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 2677936
            )

        [28] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15835882_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1471375338
                [ctime] => 1471375338
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1471375338
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [29] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15260039_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473438693
                [ctime] => 1473438693
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473438693
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [30] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14638908_region_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1473445005
                [ctime] => 1473445005
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473445005
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [31] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15835802_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 2
                [mtime] => 1473454961
                [ctime] => 1473454961
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473539959
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [32] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14502749_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1473257608
                [ctime] => 1473257608
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473271181
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [33] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14511725_region_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473342792
                [ctime] => 1473342792
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473342792
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [34] => Array
            (
                [key] => 16701314_region
                [ttl] => 120
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473603775
                [ctime] => 1473603775
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473603775
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [35] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15544722_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 2
                [mtime] => 1473163788
                [ctime] => 1473163788
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473164327
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [36] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14869156_region_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 3
                [mtime] => 1473449679
                [ctime] => 1473449679
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473449727
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [37] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14638923_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1464279681
                [ctime] => 1464279681
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1464279945
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [38] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15544732_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473271185
                [ctime] => 1473271185
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473271185
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [39] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14869156_region
                [ttl] => 120
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473449679
                [ctime] => 1473449679
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473449679
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [40] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15103658_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1456790232
                [ctime] => 1456790232
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1456790661
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [41] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14503641_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473339210
                [ctime] => 1473339210
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473339210
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [42] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14638909_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 1
                [mtime] => 1472149533
                [ctime] => 1472149533
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1472169432
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [43] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14638908_region
                [ttl] => 120
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473445005
                [ctime] => 1473445005
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473445005
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [44] => Array
            (
                [key] => 40--15103330
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 3
                [mtime] => 1456791932
                [ctime] => 1456791932
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1456791984
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 3760
            )

        [45] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15872466_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 2
                [mtime] => 1472564047
                [ctime] => 1472564047
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1472575925
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [46] => Array
            (
                [key] => 47--16701314
                [ttl] => 60
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473605193
                [ctime] => 1473605193
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473605193
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 2486448
            )

        [47] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14360206_region
                [ttl] => 120
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473438731
                [ctime] => 1473438731
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473438731
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 1200
            )

        [48] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14500848_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473257624
                [ctime] => 1473257624
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473257624
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [49] => Array
            (
                [key] => 14638908_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1473445005
                [ctime] => 1473445005
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1473445005
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

        [50] => Array
            (
                [key] => 15872536_form_id
                [ttl] => 168000
                [nhits] => 0
                [mtime] => 1472575884
                [ctime] => 1472575884
                [dtime] => 0
                [atime] => 1472575884
                [ref_count] => 0
                [mem_size] => 656
            )

    )

[deleted_list] => Array
    (
    )

[slot_distribution] => Array
    (
        [104] => 1
        [217] => 1
        [300] => 1
        [372] => 1
        [383] => 1
        [512] => 1
        [544] => 1
        [644] => 1
        [789] => 1
        [1030] => 1
        [1111] => 1
        [1151] => 1
        [1240] => 1
        [1547] => 1
        [1554] => 1
        [1622] => 1
        [1635] => 1
        [1665] => 1
        [1670] => 1
        [1692] => 1
        [1714] => 1
        [1732] => 1
        [1809] => 1
        [1856] => 1
        [1866] => 1
        [1868] => 1
        [1870] => 1
        [1882] => 1
        [1886] => 1
        [2076] => 1
        [2167] => 1
        [2593] => 1
        [2602] => 1
        [2650] => 1
        [2655] => 1
        [2714] => 1
        [2999] => 1
        [3039] => 1
        [3138] => 1
        [3161] => 1
        [3301] => 1
        [3328] => 1
        [3386] => 1
        [3426] => 1
        [3482] => 1
        [3673] => 1
        [3766] => 1
        [3786] => 1
        [3795] => 1
        [3870] => 1
        [4096] => 1
    )

)
```

Comment: you need to tag this with the framework your using

Comment: `$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));`

Therefore seems to be the apc cache that is being used.

Comment: Here is more info